# Grep when pattern is found exactly n times

Tags: r, regex

I am looking for a regex expression to capture strings where the pattern is repeated **n** times. Here is an example with expected output.

```
# find sentences with 2 occurrences of the word "is"
z = c("this is what it is and is not", "this is not", "this is it it is")
regex_function(z)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

I have gotten this far:

```
grepl("(.*\\bis\\b.*){2}",z)
[1] TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

But this will return `TRUE` if there are *at least* 2 matches. How can I force it to look for strings with exactly 2 occurrences?

Comment: `z[lengths(regmatches(z, gregexpr("\\bis\\b", z))) == 2]`

Answer (score 1):

To find where the word `is` is contained two times you can remove all `is` with `gsub` and compare the length of the strings with `nchar`.

```
nchar(z) - nchar(gsub("(\\bis\\b)", "", z)) == 4
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

or count the hits of `gregexpr` like:

```
sapply(gregexpr("\\bis\\b", z), function(x) sum(x>0)) == 2
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

or with a `regex` in `grepl`

```
grepl("^(?!(.*\\bis\\b){3})(.*\\bis\\b){2}.*$", z, perl=TRUE)
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: This works but I am still looking for a compact regex that can achieve the output. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

This is an option that works but needs 2 `regex` calls. I am still looking for a compact `regex` call which correctly solves this issue.

```
grepl("(.*\\bis\\b.*){2}",z) & !grepl("(.*\\bis\\b.*){3}",z)
```

Basically adding a `grepl` of n+1 and only keeping the ones that satisfy grep no 1 and do not satisfy grep no2.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringi)
stri_count_regex(z, "\\bis\\b") == 2L
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

with `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

regex_function = function(str){
  str_extract_all(str,"\\bis\\b")%>%
    lapply(.,function(x){length(x) == 2}) %>%
    unlist()
}

> regex_function(z)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```